Do you have to rotate orbitals in a CASSCF calculation for each of the intermediates along a reaction?
I am trying out how to do CASSCF and I am computing the energies along a reaction.
I understand that CASSCF calculations may require orbital rotations, but how do I approach it if I am to do it across all the images of a reaction? I am using ORCA, and in my input I just specified the size of the active space using the 1.98 - 0.02 occupied orbitals of my structure with the most smearing, which is the TS since I am simulating an E/Z isomerization.
If I have n intermediates, do I manually have to do n preliminary electronic structure calculations for each, and then do n orbital rotations as I deem fit?
